# Is it possible to select the file name in a JFileChooser window?

Tags: java, swing

I can set the default File Name: in a JFileChooser window using:

```
fileChooser.setSelectedFile();
```

I was wondering if it is also possible to select it, so that if you want to save the file as something else you can immediately start to overtype it. Thanks for any help on this.

```
package filetest;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Editor {

    public static class TextClass extends JTextArea {

        FileClass fileClass = new FileClass();

        public void setKeyboardShortcuts() {
            fileClass.setKeyboardShortcuts();
        }

        private class FileClass {

            private File directory;
            private String filepath = "";
            private String filename = "";

            private void setKeyboardShortcuts() {

                Action ctrlo = new AbstractAction() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            openFile();
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                        }
                    }
                };
                getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl O"), "ctrlo");
                getActionMap().put("ctrlo", ctrlo);

                Action ctrls = new AbstractAction() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            saveFile();
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                        }
                    }
                };
                getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl S"), "ctrls");
                getActionMap().put("ctrls", ctrls);
            }

            private String selectFile(String fileaction) throws FileNotFoundException { 
                JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
                if (directory != null) {
                    filechooser.setCurrentDirectory(directory);
                } else {
                    filechooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
                }
                filechooser.setSelectedFile(new File(filepath));
                int r = 0;
                if (fileaction.equals("openfile"))
                    r = filechooser.showDialog(new JPanel(), "Open file");
                else
                    r = filechooser.showDialog(new JPanel(), "Save file");
                if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        directory = filechooser.getSelectedFile().getParentFile();
                        filename = filechooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
                        return filename;
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        return "";
                    }
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            }

            private void openFile() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
                try {
                    String filestr = selectFile("openfile");
                    if (filestr.equals(""))
                        return;
                    else
                        filepath = filestr;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            private void saveFile() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {   
                try {
                    String filestr = selectFile("savefile");
                    if (filestr.equals(""))
                        return;
                    else
                        filepath = filestr;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JTextArea textArea = new TextClass();
        frame.add(textArea);
        ((TextClass) textArea).setKeyboardShortcuts();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "select it"?

Comment: Highlight the text in the field, and give the field focus, so that when you start typing the existing text is replaced. As would be the case if you clicked in the File Name: field and pressed Ctrl+A.

Comment: This is the default behaviour for me. I'm using JDK8 on Windows 7. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem so others can test your code.

Answer (score 0):

It does that by default on the machine I'm typing from:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

/**
 *
 * @author ub
 */
public class StackOverflow
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images", "jpg", "gif","png");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.setSelectedFile(new File("C:\\Users\\ub\\Pictures\\Capt.PNG"));
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
           System.out.println("You chose to open this file: "+chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: JDK8 x86_64 on Win

Comment: Hi, that works for me too, but my version (code added above) does not.

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you first call `.setSelectedFile` your `filepath` is an empty string.

You set your `filepath` variable *after* having shown the file chooser to the user.

If you print to console the string value of `filepath`, right before invoking `.showDialog`, you should see this.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain what I was trying to do very clearly, The filepath variable is an empty string when a file is first opened. It then contains the name of the opened file, and is used to populate the File Name: field when saving the file. If you press Ctrl+O and choose a file, then press Ctrl+S, the file name should be displayed. The problem is that it is not highlighted, whereas the file name in your example is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be caused by these lines:

```
try {
    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

If they are removed, the file name is highlighted as in Unai Vivi's example.