# Selecting text in JFileChooser File Name field when using Nimbus

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jfilechooser, nimbus

I originally asked a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916878/is-it-possible-to-select-the-file-name-in-a-jfilechooser-window) on selecting the file name in a JFileChooser dialog. It now appears that the actual problem is with Nimbus: when using it, the text in the File Name field is not automatically selected. I'm trying to work out how to do so programatically.

Using some code I got from an answer to a question on how to disable the File Name field I can locate the relevant JTextField (example below).

Disabling it using:

```
setEnabled(false);
```

works perfectly. However, I need to do something like:

```
setSelectionStart(0);
setSelectionEnd(textField.getText().length());
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
                showFileChooser();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void showFileChooser() {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setSelectedFile(new File("C:\\SomeFile.txt"));
        selectFileName(chooser);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
    }

    private static boolean selectFileName(Container cont) {
        Component[] cmps = cont.getComponents();
        for (Component cmp : cmps) {
            if (cmp instanceof JTextField) {

                ((JTextField) cmp).setSelectionStart(0);
                ((JTextField) cmp).setSelectionEnd(((JTextField) cmp).getText().length());
                System.out.println(((JTextField) cmp).getSelectedText());
                ((JTextField) cmp).requestFocusInWindow();

                return true;
            }
            if (cmp instanceof Container) {
                if (selectFileName(((Container) cmp)))
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot select in a disabled text field

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify. If you remove the comments from
                    
    /*((JTextField) cmp).setSelectionStart(0);
    ((JTextField) cmp).setSelectionEnd(((JTextField)cmp).getText().length());
     System.out.println(((JTextField) cmp).getSelectedText());
     ((JTextField) cmp).requestFocusInWindow();*/ 

and add them to

    ((JTextField) cmp).setEnabled(false);

you should see what I mean. The text "SomeFile.txt" in the File Name field is not selected.

Comment: my first comment actually states that. You cannot select text in a textfield that is disabled.

Comment: I've edited the code above to clarify what I am trying to do. Hope it makes more sense now!

Comment: Could you exactly specify what you want? do you want to show the selected file in the jtextfield and have all the text selected?

Comment: The line 'chooser.setSelectedFile(new File("C:\\SomeFile.txt"));' causes the words 'SomeFile.txt' to be displayed in the JTextField. If you don't use Nimbus the text is automatically selected, and as soon as you start typing it is replaced by whatever you type. If you do use Nimbus, the text is not selected automatically. You have to click in the text field and press Ctrl+A to select it. Only then can you overtype it. I'm trying to find a way to select the text in the JTextField programmatically.